# Elastic search memory management and heap alert

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using an elastic cloud to store my data. my elastic cloud heap size is 4.6GB. But I am getting alert from the elastic cloud :

> Elastic cloud cluster Heap Memory usage is more than 70%.

How can I reduce the heap memory usage?
What are the reasons for this high heap memory usage?

Comment: we can't answer you without knowing the amount of data you are indexing. How many indices do you have? How many shards and so on... BTW 4.6GB for a heap size is not a big value.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of elastic search memory management but currently, I am having 445 total indexes and my data size is 6.8GB.and having 4.6GB heap size. Please let me know what is wrong here so the alerts are coming?